# Anyone know of an easier way to write this code in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, list, frontend

I was watching an React Tutorial and the instructor did not explain a part very well for me to understand. He was basically trying teach how to render the list dynamically in three different input boxes. Whatever is typed in each input box will render to the according div element above it. And the instructor told us we should not touch the state directly which was where this code got more complicated. Any easier way to write this code? Not understanding him. The code that instructor instructed is in the ***nameChangeHandler*** function. Please see code below. Thanks!

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Person from "./Person/Person"

class App extends React.Component {

  state={
    persons: [
      {id: 1,name: "Max", age:28 },
      {id:2,name: "Manu", age: 29},
      {id:3, name: "Stephanie", age: 26 }
    ],
    showPersons: false
  }

  deletePersonHandler=(index)=> {
   const persons = [...this.state.persons];
   persons.splice(index, 1)
   this.setState({ persons: persons});
   console.log(persons)
  }

  nameChangedHandler = (e, id ) => {
    const personIndex = this.state.persons.findIndex(p=> {
      return p.id === id;
    })

    const person = {
      ...this.state.persons[personIndex]
    };

    person.name= e.target.value;

    const persons = [...this.state.persons];
    persons[personIndex] = person;

    this.setState({
      persons: persons
    })

  }

  togglePersonsHandler=()=> {
    const showing = this.state.showPersons;
    this.setState({ showPersons: !showing })
  }


  render() {

    const style={
      backgroundColor: "white",
      font:"inherit",
      border:"1px solid blue",
      padding:"8px",
      cursor:"pointer"
    }

    let persons=null;
    if(this.state.showPersons) {
      persons=(
      <div>
        {this.state.persons.map((person, index)=> {
          return(
            <Person 
              key={person.id}
              changed={(e)=>this.nameChangedHandler(e, person.id)}
              click={()=>this.deletePersonHandler(index)}
              name={person.name} 
              age={person.age}/>
          )
        })}
      </div>)
    }
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1>Hi, Im a React App</h1>
        <p>This is really working!!!</p>
        <button style={style} onClick={this.togglePersonsHandler}>Toggle Persons</button>
        {persons}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

[image: Image of my app]

Comment: If you can point out more precisely what is it that you do not understand I am very bored and willing to help, I read it all, it is all pretty clear to me.

Comment: Could you breifly explain to me the reasoning behind the lines of code written in the nameChangeHandler? And where the values are coming from? If its not too much work for you. Thanks!

Comment: There you go, added an answer.

Answer (score 1):

As per your request in the comments here is a brief explenation of this code:

```
nameChangedHandler = (e, id ) => {
  const personIndex = this.state.persons.findIndex(p=> {
    return p.id === id;
  })
```

What you see is an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions). For the purpose of this entire answer, treat them as normal function (it is not the same, however it could be done with regular functions as well). Semantically speaking, arrow functions or regular functions does not change what the code is doing/its intention so I will not go into details, you should just be aware of what you are seeing. If you are unfamiliar with them though, you should read up on it, they are very useful. The signature for an arrow function is either `(a,b) => {}`, `a => {}` or `a => <expression>`. So roughly speaking the above can be logically interpreted as `function(e,id){}` and `function(p){}` just to clear that up before I proceed (it would not work if written that way, but that is the message it conveys).

The code itself extracts the index of the person that matches the `id` parameter that you passed to the nameChangeHandler. This is done using [findIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex), a function that iterates through the array (`.persons` array of your state in this case), and returns the index of the first element that passes the test function given. This index is then stored inside a variable for usage later in the code.

### The values

`e` and `id` are coming from invocation of the function itself, I cannot give you more detail, since I do not see what the `<Person>` class is, but it is safe to assume that this handler is being attached to an input field. Once a change happens via the `onChange` handler on an input field, react will trigger a handler and pass an `event` containing the event data to it. Your handler is actually not the `nameChangeHandler` function, it is an arrow function which takes an `event e`, and then calls the `nameChangeHandler` passing both the `event e` as well as the `id` for the person, you can see that here `changed={(e)=>this.nameChangedHandler(e, person.id)}`. Rest of the values are read from your `state`.

Let's continue with the code:

```
const person = {
  ...this.state.persons[personIndex]
};
```

What we have here is called a [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax). It essentially "unpacks and repacks" the object or an array, you can read more about it on the MDN link given. This is a powerful new feature of ES6 that makes life a lot easier.

So the above code is used to cleverly **shallow copy** a person object from the array into a new local variable (or rather a `const`, since variable would imply a possibility of change).We do this because in javascript, object data is stored by reference, so we cannot simply change the person object inside the initial array, that would mutate the state. We do not want to mutate the state. Immutable is the key here.

```
person.name= e.target.value;
```

Following that we have a simple asignment. The new `person` object we just created is an exact (sort of) copy of what the person inside the state's `.persons` array was, and that is no good, we want to change the name, so we do exactly that. We access the `event e` and read the `value` of the `target` that triggered it, assign the new value to our `person` object, and now we have a "changed man" (pun intended).

What is left for us to do is, push these changes into the state so that a new render can show them, so we do:

```
const persons = [...this.state.persons];
persons[personIndex] = person;
```

This code again uses the **spread** to clone/copy an old array from the state into a new local array persons. It is equvivalent to using `const persons = this.state.persons.slice()`. You can read more about `.slice()` on the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/) (intentionally not leaving a direct link for you so that you search for it and learn that part as well, MDN is really a great source for documentation of all sorts and getting to know your way around that website is a lifesaver.). Lastly, after the array is cloned, we find the original person and replace it with out local person object, that has a changed name.

```
this.setState({
  persons: persons
})
```

Lastly we use the `.setState` method that react provides (see [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate)) to immutably change the state. This change will trigger a new `render()` and you will be able to see the changes in the UI. The `.setState()` itself operates by doing a **shallow merge**. This means that only the properties that you pass to the method itself will be changed/added to the state, rest of the properties will be kept, as-is. Since the only thing we pass is a different array of `persons` which is our local array, with the changed person, that is the only thing that changes.

Answer (score 0):

When updating local state based off of current local state, you should be using the setState callback pattern, because of the way calls to `this.setState` are batched by React.

Also, shallow-copy and update is perfectly fine, however you could also use the standard `Array.prototype.map` method to perform the update:

```
nameChangedHandler = (e, id ) => {
  this.setState((prevState) => {
     const persons = prevState.persons.map(person, i => {
       return i === id ? { ...person, name: e.target.name } : person;
     });

    return {
      persons: persons,
    };
  });     
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, { Component} from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Person from './Person/Person';


class App  extends Component{
  state = {
    persons : [
      {id:1, name : 'sohan',    age : 28},
      {id:2, name : 'Rohan',    age : 29},
      {id:3, name : 'Stephani', age : 21}
    ],
    otherState : 'hiii',
    showPersons : false
  }

 

 nameChangeHandler = (event, id)=>{
const personInedex = this.state.persons.find(p => {
  return p.id === id;
})

personInedex.name = event.target.value;



  this.setState({persons:this.state.persons})
 }

  toglePerson = ()=>{
    this.setState({showPersons:!this.state.showPersons})
  }

  delete = (item) =>{
  const persons = [...this.state.persons];
  persons.splice(item, 1);
  this.setState({persons: persons});
  }
 
 render(){
   const style = {
     backgroundColor: '#88dc707d',
     margin: 0,
     font: 'inherit',
     padding : '15px',
     cursor: 'pointer',
     color: 'white',
     boxShadow: '15px 10px 12px grey',
     borderRadius: '22px 5px 22px 5px'
   }
   let persons = null
 if(this.state.showPersons){
   persons = (
      <div>
        {this.state.persons.map((item, index) => {
          return   <Person key={item.id} 
                         name={item.name} 
                         age={item.age}
                onchange={(event) => this.nameChangeHandler(event, item.id)}
          deleteName={()=> this.delete(index)} />
          })}
        
      </div> 
   )
 }
 return (
    <div className="App">
     <h1> hii i am React App</h1>
     <button 
      style={style}
       onClick={this.toglePerson}>Togle Name</button>
      {persons}
    </div>
  );
 }
}

export default App;

// state = {
//   persons : [
//     {name : 'sohan', age : 28},
//     {name : 'Rohan', age : 29},
//     {name : 'Stephani', age : 21}
//   ],
//   otherState : 'hiii'
// }

//  switchNameHandler = () => {
//    console.log(this.state)
//    this.setState({
//     persons : [
//       {name : 'Sudan Lal', age : 28},
//       {name : 'Rohan', age : 29},
//       {name : 'Stephani', age : 25}`enter code here`
//     ]
//   })
// }
```